# Dealing with attribute errors in Python

Tags: python, function, user-interface, typeerror, attributeerror

Essentially, I'm learning GUI in Python and I'm trying to have my program take input from a user. Based on the input from the user, I want my code to return different messages. However, I keep getting different errors based on the changes I make to fix my code.

My original code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

def get_BMI():
        global heightEntry
        global weightEntry
        global nameEntry
        global BMI
        nameEntry = nameEntry.get()
        heightEntry = int(heightEntry.get())
        weightEntry = int(weightEntry.get())
        BMI = ((weightEntry * 703) // (heightEntry ** 2))

        if heightEntry <= 0 or weightEntry <= 0:
           showinfo(message='Error: height and weight must be positive values')

        elif heightEntry.isdigit() == False or weightEntry.isdigit() == False:
            showinfo(message= 'height and weight must be numbers')

        else:
            showinfo(message=f' {nameEntry} your BMI is {BMI}.')
        nameEntry.delete(0, 'end')
        weightEntry.delete(0, 'end')
        heightEntry.delete(0, 'end')

root = Tk()

root.title('BMI Calculator')

name = Label(root, text='Enter your name')
name.grid(row=1, column=0)
nameEntry = Entry(root)
nameEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)

height = Label(root, text='Enter your height (in)')
height.grid(row=2, column=0)
heightEntry = Entry(root)
heightEntry.grid(row=2, column=1
             )
weight = Label(root, text='Enter your weight(lb)')
weight.grid(row=3, column=0)
weightEntry = Entry(root)
weightEntry.grid(row=3, column=1)

calculateBMI = Button(root, text='Calculate BMI', command=get_BMI)
calculateBMI.grid(row=4, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

original error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\16787\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\16787\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.1\scratches\maincode.py", line 17, in get_BMI
    elif heightEntry.isdigit() == False or weightEntry.isdigit() == False:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

new code:

```
heightEntry = heightEntry.get() #<<<<<< took off the int function
weightEntry = weightEntry.get() #<<<<<< took off the int function
```

new error:
'''C:\Users\16787\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\16787\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.1\scratches\maincode.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\16787\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1921, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\16787\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.1\scratches\maincode.py", line 12, in get_BMI
BMI = ((weightEntry * 703) // (heightEntry ** 2))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
'''

I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: `heightEntry = heightEntry.get()` Don't reuse the same variable name for both things.  Call one of them something else, like `heightValue`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to make the variable name different from the widget name.
And I think you need to tweak your logic a bit.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

def get_BMI():
    name_var = nameEntry.get()
    try:
        height_var = int(heightEntry.get())
        weight_var = int(weightEntry.get())
        BMI = ((weight_var * 703) // (height_var ** 2))
        if height_var <= 0 or weight_var <= 0:
            showinfo(message='Error: height and weight must be positive values')
        else:
            showinfo(message=f' {name_var} your BMI is {BMI}.')
    except ValueError:
        showinfo(message='height and weight must be numbers')
    nameEntry.delete(0, 'end')
    weightEntry.delete(0, 'end')
    heightEntry.delete(0, 'end')

root = Tk()

root.title('BMI Calculator')

name = Label(root, text='Enter your name')
name.grid(row=1, column=0)
nameEntry = Entry(root)
nameEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)

height = Label(root, text='Enter your height (in)')
height.grid(row=2, column=0)
heightEntry = Entry(root)
heightEntry.grid(row=2, column=1
             )
weight = Label(root, text='Enter your weight(lb)')
weight.grid(row=3, column=0)
weightEntry = Entry(root)
weightEntry.grid(row=3, column=1)

calculateBMI = Button(root, text='Calculate BMI', command=get_BMI)
calculateBMI.grid(row=4, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps.